# Elasticsearch on Windows: elasticsearch.bat throws errors

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to install Elasticsearch on a Windows machine. I have the right version of Java and downloaded and unzipped Elasticsearch. When I try to run elasticsearch.bat, it won't run. I get the following errors:

```
./elasticsearch.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
./elasticsearch.bat: line 3: SETLOCAL: command not found
./elasticsearch.bat: line 4: TITLE: command not found
./elasticsearch.bat: line 6: SET: command not found
./elasticsearch.bat: line 8: :loop: command not found
./elasticsearch.bat: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./elasticsearch.bat: line 9: `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims= " %%A IN (!params!) DO ('
```

I have no idea where these errors come from and would be very grateful if anyone could tell me why this happens and how to solve it.

Comment: I have just solved the problem. As it turned out, the JAVA_HOME variable wasn't set properly, once I got this sorted everything worked.